# How can I get the final result using MathNet.Symbolics?

Tags: c#, equation, math.net

I am trying to make  a method that will calculate a determinant. For that I am using the MathNet.Symbolics library. All good until I run into a little problem. I was trying to get the final result from the formula of a determinant and after I used `Infix.Format`, I don't know why, but it does not give ma a satisfying result. Instead of the final result It gives me an equation somewhere in between. I think is has something to do with the fact that part of the equation is between 2 parentheses. What should I do to get the final Result?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using InputMath;
using MathNet.Symbolics;
using mns = MathNet.Symbolics.Expression;

namespace MathWizard
{
     class Determinants
    {
        //The final result
        public static string fnalResult;

        public static void BasicDeterminant()
        {
            //The inputs before assigning them to theyr specific variable
            string[] inputs;

            inputs = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Double x1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[0]);
            Double y1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[1]);

            Double x2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[2]); 
            Double y2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[3]);

            var x = mns.Symbol("x");
            var y = mns.Symbol("y");

            var firstResult = Infix.Format(x * x1 * 1 + x1 * y2 * 1 + x2 * y * 1 - (x1 * x2 * 1 + 1 * y2 * x + 1 * y * x1));

            Console.WriteLine(firstResult);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

So this is an example input:

1 3 6 4

After input the numbers will be assigned like this:

```
x1 = 1;
y1 = 3;
x2 = 6;
y2 = 4;
```

After running all the code the output is:

4 + x + 6*y - (6 + 4*x + y)

After solving this output, the actual expected result should be:

-2-3*x+7*y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.NET Symbolics does apply automatic simplification, but only according strict rules. That's why some of the terms are simplified and reordered, but the parenthesis is not automatically expanded.

You can use the symbolic routine `Algebraic.Expand` to enforce the expansion:

```
var expression = x * x1 * 1 + x1 * y2 * 1 + x2 * y * 1 - (x1 * x2 * 1 + 1 * y2 * x + 1 * y * x1);
var expanded = Algebraic.Expand(expression);
var firstResult = Infix.Format(expanded);
```

Where `firstResult` now has the expected value `(-2) + (-3)*x + 5*y`.

NB: I notice it would be nicer if this would have been formatted as `-2 - 3*x + 5*y`. I'll try to improve this in the next release.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your time and effort. Have a very nice day!